# break if statement and continue loop

Tags: php

how to break a if statement in foreach and continue loop?
i used break; but it closing the loop too :(

```
 foreach($arry as $s){
        
        if(trim($row['img1']) == ''){
            $insrt="UPDATE testt SET img1=:img1";
            $r=$connect->prepare($insrt);
            $r->bindparam(":img1",$s);
            $r->execute();
            echo"$s";
            break;
        }elseif(trim($row['img2']) == ''){  
            $insrt="UPDATE testt SET img2=:img2";
            $r=$connect->prepare($insrt);
            $r->bindparam(":img2",$s);
            $r->execute();
            echo"$s";
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Try `continue` instead. However, in your code you shouldn't need to add that. The loop will continue after the if-statements

Comment: An `if` statement doesn't need a `break`, just (in this case) the close `}` which matches the `{`

Comment: You should also have your 2 Prepare's done before the loop, and the bind and execute inside the loop. Save yourself count($array) unnecessary round trips to the database compiling the same 2 queries again and again unnecessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nigel Ren already commented what I was going to say but I'm adding it as an answer anyway. If statements don't need a `break` or `continue`. Look at this example:

```
foreach(...) {
  if(condition) {
    //will work only if the condition is true
  } else {
    //will work if the condition is not true
  }

  //will always work (after if-else block) as long as the loop continues
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only break when you really want to stop the loop.

In your case I'm guessing you want to loop until the end so no break is needed.

You can use a break when you get invalid if/elseif.

So you could put a continue in your if and in your elseif statement and a break after the last elseif (outside of the if elseif statements)

```
foreach($arry as $s){
    
    if(trim($row['img1']) == ''){
        $insrt="UPDATE testt SET img1=:img1";
        $r=$connect->prepare($insrt);
        $r->bindparam(":img1",$s);
        $r->execute();
        echo"$s";
        continue;
    }elseif(trim($row['img2']) == ''){  
        $insrt="UPDATE testt SET img2=:img2";
        $r=$connect->prepare($insrt);
        $r->bindparam(":img2",$s);
        $r->execute();
        echo"$s";
        continue;
    } 
break;
}
```